# Minimal height of a dishwasher drain

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

I installed the drain pipe as shown here and I'll use a high loop for the tube but the installation instructions specify that it should be plugged at at least 18". Is this setup problematic?

[image]

Comment: how high is the floor of the cabinet you are measuring against compared to the floor the dishwasher is standing on?

Comment: @ratchetfreak right... that adds an extra 5 inches. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

18" is the minimum height if you're using a *stand pipe*.

IDK any code that says you can't put a barbed fitting anywhere you want in a vertical drain line.

> if a residential DW drain hose is looped up up top of appliance (as most modern appliances are already) you can drain the discharge to below floor level & into a standpipe if that standpipe is at least 18" long & that drain branch is protected with a backflow or backwater device to prevent flooding into crawlspace.

https://www.diychatroom.com/threads/ok-to-route-dishwasher-drain-under-the-floor.617426/